# Configure anonymous access for static file from appsettings.json or startup.cs

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, appsettings, microsoft-identity-platform

I am writing an ASP.NET Core 5 app. There is an Azure configuration to prove you own an identity that required you to host an file at this location:

```
https://yoursite.com/.well-known/microsoft-identity-association.json
```

So I created a directory in the `wwwroot` folder of my project alongside 'css' and 'js' and name the file accordingly.

However the path is authorized, and I need to make it available with Anonymous Access.

In the ASP.NET classic (.NET Framework), we could use a `<location href=".well-known">` element to configure settings specific to that server relative path.

Is there an equivalent in ASP.NET Core's `appsettings.json`, to allow anonymous access by path?

Comment: Can you output the JSON in a Controller marked with `[AllowAnonymous]`?

Comment: @JeremyThompson that will do... I guess I would need a ROUTE() header to set the path. or perhaps something custom in the route table.  the URL is pretty specific

Comment: Maybe a wildcard route like `.well-known/{*path}` and then check the path matches.

Comment: can I set anonymous access in the route table definition? can I handle this all with some code in "startup.cs" instead of appsettings file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @jeremy-thompson ... here is my solution.

```
[AllowAnonymous]
[Route(".well-known/microsoft-identity-association.json")]
public IActionResult MSIdentityAssoc()
{
    return Json(new
    {
        associatedApplications = new[]
        {
            new { applicationId = Guid.Parse("xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxyyyyzzzz") }
        }
    });
}
```